# Construct 2 game crash in Android Webview

Tags: android, multithreading, java-native-interface, android-webview, construct-2

**Problem Description**

We have made games using construct 2 and playing it on android native Webview with game link. But randomly after some time we are getting this crash.

**Crash log**

```
W: Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?): Thread[25,tid=17363,Native,Thread*=0x88542000,peer=0x12e45340,"Thread-22012"]
A: art/runtime/thread.cc:1237] Native thread exited without calling DetachCurrentThread: Thread[25,tid=17363,Native,Thread*=0x88542000,peer=0x12e45340,"Thread-22012"]
A: art/runtime/runtime.cc:368] Runtime aborting...
A: art/runtime/runtime.cc:368] 
W: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W: Chrome build fingerprint:
W: 1.21
W: 22
W: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
A: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 17363 (Thread-22012)
```

We have not made any JNI calls. Has anyone faced this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of games are in your app? Or what does your Webview do?

Comment: Playing this game in webview with this link: https://bucketeer-297aee65-9d1a-494a-bc24-c72553ed097e.s3.amazonaws.com/public/355/index.html
On loading this in webview, then the app will crashed after 2 or 3 minutes.

Comment: In what is that game programmed?

Comment: Javascript.. using construct 2